# Sprig "Load more" not loading over https

Tags: ssl, https, craftcms, sprig-template-functions

I've recently added an SSL to the site I'm working on, and it seems to have broken my "load more" buttons via [sprig](https://putyourlightson.com/sprig/cookbook#load-more). When I click the button now, I get

> Blocked loading mixed active content “http://mydomainname.net/index.php?p=actions/sprig/components/render&offset=6&sprig%3AsiteId=32200a47f3a91660d5c53896017cd9e51baccf7f69c571407279fa99ecbcffb91&sprig%3Atemplate=0fb8ec651fc53258017209d22d4e19b6143ac209993784d01a06801fd13e9cd6_layouts%2F_blog%2F_loadMore&sprig%3Avariables%5Blimit%5D=15a1fe68dab9e8d01fdd3bc84980fa5d354e5c72f0e00d06e0841462638f363d6”

and

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://www.mydomainname.net/index.php?p=actions/sprig/components/render&offset=6&sprig%3AsiteId=32200a47f3a91660d5c53896017cd9e51baccf7f69c571407279fa99ecbcffb91&sprig%3Atemplate=0fb8ec651fc53258017209d22d4e19b6143ac209993784d01a06801fd13e9cd6_layouts%2F_blog%2F_loadMore&sprig%3Avariables%5Blimit%5D=15a1fe68dab9e8d01fdd3bc84980fa5d354e5c72f0e00d06e0841462638f363d6. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed).

errors in my console. I've noticed that the cross origin error is trying to load stuff over **https** but the mixed active content error is trying to load over **http**.

How can I get this working again over **https**?

Here's my sprig code if you need it:

```
{{ sprig('_layouts/_blog/_loadMore', {'limit': 6}) }}
{{ sprig.script }}
```

```
{% set offset = offset ?? 0 %}

{% set entryQuery = craft.entries.section('diggingDeeper').offset(offset).limit(limit) %}
{% set entries = entryQuery.all() %}

{% for entry in entries %}

    ----Entry Stuff----

{% endfor %}

            
{% if entryQuery.count() > offset + entries|length %}
  <button class="orange-button" sprig s-val:offset="{{ offset + limit }}" 
    s-target="this" s-swap="outerHTML">
    <p>Load More</p>
  </button>
{% endif %}
```

**Edit:**
Added the full errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it figured out, full answer [HERE](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/37470/10770). Long story short, there were two problems.

1. In my `.htaccess` file, I was forcing the removal of `www` from my
   domain. That code was calling up `http` instead of `https`. Adding
   the "s" resolved one of the errors.
2. Even though I was forcing the removal of `www` in my `.htaccess`
   file, my root domain was still using `www`, which caused an error. So removing `www` from my root domain fixed the second error.